# In Rust, what's the most idiomatic way to convert a result to another result given the Error type is convertible

Tags: rust, rust-result

Let's say I call a function that returns me `Result<Foo, Error1>` and want to return `Result<Foo, Error2>`. `Error2` implements `From<Error1>`.

The two options I have in mind are

```
fn f1() -> Result<Foo, Error2> {
  f2().map_err(|e| e.into())
}
```

or

```
fn f1() -> Result<Foo, Error2> {
  Ok(f2()?)
}
```

Is there a third, more idiomatic option? If not, which one should be preferred of the two?

I was expecting `f2.into()` to work out of the box, but it only works if `From<Result<Foo, Error1>>` is implemented for `Result<Foo, Error2>`.

Comment: From my experience, you'd find `Ok(f2()?)` much more common in the wild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A third option is to use `Into::into` directly in your call to `map_err`, like so:

```rust
fn f1() -> Result<Foo, Error2> {
  f2().map_err(Into::into)
}
```

This is preferred over using a closure. Clippy actually has a lint for this: [redundant_closure](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/v0.0.212/#redundant_closure).

This option is the most explicit in what it is doing. To an outside reader, there is no question how the conversion is happening. Contrastingly, while `Ok(f2()?)` works, the conversion is implicit and it is not immediately obvious how it is happening.